# How to make a video capture of a VirtualBox session?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm looking for a way to bring virtual machine up and record its session as video. I know there is a little camera icon in the corner but I'm looking for a way to scrip this so need a command line option. I went through VirtualBox manual but I can't see the appropriate command. 
I found an option for taking a screen shoot

```
VBoxManage controlvm <vm name> screenshotpng <filename>.png
```

still no video option to be found... Please help !

Comment: I think it was something with VBoxHeadles -c for capturing the video...can you try that

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The information you need is in the section [8.8.4. Video Capture settings](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvm-videocap) and in the section [8.13. VBoxManage controlvm](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-controlvm) of the documentation.

The main options are:

> **--videocap on|off**: This option enables or disables recording a VM session into a WebM/VP8 file. If this option is enabled, recording will start when the VM session is started.
>
> **--videocapfile** : This option sets the filename VirtualBox uses to save the recorded content.
>
> **--videocapres x**: This option sets the resolution (in pixels) of the recorded video.
>
> **--videocapmaxtime** : This option sets the maximum time in milliseconds the video capturing will be enabled since activation. The capturing stops when the defined time interval has elapsed. If this value is zero the capturing is not limited by time.

Running

```
VBoxManage modifyvm <vm name> --videocap on
```

on a stopped virtual machine will activate the video capture on next boot. This will be active only once.

Running

```
VBoxManage controlvm <vm name> videocap on
```

on a running virtual machine will start the video capture.

Running

```
VBoxManage controlvm <vm name> videocap off
```

on a running virtual machine will stop the video capture.

By default the video capture is recorded in a `<vm name>.webm` file in the same directory as the vm files.

Note also that you have to use double dash (`--`) when using `modifyvm` (because `videocap`, `videocapfile`, `videocapres`,... are options here) but **not** when using `controlvm` (because `videocap`, `videocapfile`, `videocapres`,... are subcommands there).